# XML all elements to list

Tags: c#, xml

My problem is with Xml file, which to look :
    This isn't work.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> stepsList = doc.Elements();
```

XML file

```
<OneGoal>
<Goal>100000</Goal>
<StepOne>ewewewe</StepOne>
<StepTwo>wee</StepTwo>
<StepThree>MY</StepThree>
<StepFour>wwwww</StepFour>
<StepFive>ddddw</StepFive>
<StepSix>fcd</StepSix>
<StepSeven>blblblfl</StepSeven>
<StepEight>z dwadddddsssssssssssss</StepEight>
<StepNine>radwds</StepNine>
<StepTen>
 blblblblblblb
</StepTen>
<DateDay>18</DateDay>
<DateMonth>7</DateMonth>
<DateYear>2019</DateYear>
</OneGoal>
```

I want all elements to IEnumberable . Earlier all elements have name 'step'.

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: first element have all file xml.

Comment: Can you show us how `doc` is created? If it is of type `XDocument` then your code should be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about converting your flat xml to `Dictionary<string,string>`?

```
var dict = XDocument.Parse(xml)
           .Element("OneGoal")
           .Elements()
           .ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value);

Console.WriteLine(dict["StepOne"]);
```

Comment: This is it !. Good option.

Answer (score 1):

Use `XDocument` to load from a file or parse from a string.

```
var stepList = doc.Descendants();
```

Comment: This is good, which @L.B got better method, thx !